# Elsa Workflow best practice short living workflow

Tags: elsa-workflows

I have a **short-living** elsaworkflow.

It gets a list of tasks passed, and the workflow should rearrange the tasks in some given ways.

For this, some actions are grouped in a workflow.

Currently, I'm working with the WorkflowExecutionContext.Input.
For example, the `GoToFirstTask`action looks like this:

```
if (context.WorkflowExecutionContext.Input is Worksheet wks)
{
    wks.CurrentTask= wks.TaskPool.First();
}
```

Is this the intended way? Or should I think about context providers?

Can someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems fine to me. Although you might indeed consider implementing a context provider, I doubt it adds much benefits.

Here's what it would look like to implement a context provider:

```cs
public class WorksheetContextProvider : ILoadWorkflowContext
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes => new[] { typeof(Worksheet) };
    
    public ValueTask<object?> LoadAsync(LoadWorkflowContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return ValueTask.FromResult(context.WorkflowExecutionContext.Input as Worksheet);
    }
}
```

Now, if your workflow definition's Workflow Context Type is configured with the `Worksheet` assembly-qualified typename, the workflow runner will invoke your custom context provider before executing the workflow.

Your activities would no be able to do this:

```cs
if (context.WorkflowExecutionContext.WorkflowContext is Worksheet wks)
{
    wks.CurrentTask= wks.TaskPool.First();
}
```

As you can see, it's almost similar, and even has a slight disadvantage: the workflow now must be configured with the context type (`MyAssembly.Domain.Entities.Worksheet, MyAssembly`). Which doesn't help the user.

Your approach is good because it allows for simple usage from the user's point of view.